# How to parse three xml files in Android Application

Tags: java, android, xml

I did the parsing for single xml file and I displayed the values in `textview`.  I tried with 3 xml files but couldn't find the exact way to parse 3 xml files, I'm not able to find my problem.

The code is provided below. Can anyone give suggestions.

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);

try {
    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();

    SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();


    DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

        boolean name = false;

        boolean salary = false;


        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                                 Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
                name = true;
            }
            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("salary")) {
                salary = true;
            }
        }//end of startElement method  

        public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
                               String qName) throws SAXException {
        }

        public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
            if (name) {

                tv.setText(tv.getText() + "\n" + new String(ch, start, length));
                name = false;
            }
            if (salary) {
                tv1.setText(tv1.getText() + "\n" + new String(ch, start, length));
                salary = false;
            }
        }//end of characters  

    };//end of DefaultHandler object  

    InputStream is = getAssets().open("file.xml");
    saxParser.parse(is, handler);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: InputStream is = getAssets().open("file.xml"); so you are fixing the file name, convert this entire code to a function and pass filename as parameter

Comment: tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"\n" + new String(ch, start, length));
Like setText() for textview what is the way of getting image in imageview.